# Rails3: If X belong_to Y, how do I display all X regardless of Y?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am experimenting to create something similar to Twitter.

In my app, posts belong to users, and users has many posts.

Now, I know how to display posts of one particular user sorted by submission time.

But I am not sure how to display all posts of all users in one page sorted by submission time.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
def stream
  @post = Post.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: So it doesn't matter that the posts belong to users?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "it doesn't matter". If you want to show all posts without considering the users. The shown code is a way of doing it...

Comment: Ok, I thought that I had to consider data tree and stuff to sort posts when it has "belong_to" some other class.

Comment: But you said you wanted to show the posts of all users--that's just Post.all, right? The only other criteria you mentioned was creation time.

Answer (score 2):

`Post.order(:submission_time)`

Comment: So it doesn't matter that the posts belong to users?

Comment: Not if your database looks how I think it looks, try it.